# keyboard shortcut for class object in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

```
class Demo{
    static void  Test(){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Is there any keyboard shortcut in eclipse for creating an object of a class declared above .

e.g after writing Demo followed by that shortcut , it should write as below

```
Demo objname = new Demo();
```

Comment: "e.g after writing Demo followed by that shortcut" how about `objname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do exactly that, but this is close:

Type `new Demo()` then `ctrl-2 L` (Quick Assist - Assign to local variable).

Eclipse will change the line to `Demo demo = new Demo();` and give you a chance to rename the variable.